# Phaser 3 Collision from a specific side of an object

Tags: collision, phaser-framework

I'm working on a platformer and one thing I want to make for it are bounce pads. But to do that, I need a way for the effect take place only if the player touches the object from the top, while nothing happens if they touch it from the sides or bottom.

The following code is for an object, a stool, for which I've made a similar effect to what I want:

```
if(this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.stool) && Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.keyW)) {
        this.p1.body.setVelocityY(-800);
        console.log(this.p1.velocityY);
    }
```

This code allows the player to jump higher if they are touching the stool. While this solution is ok in some places, what I really want is for the effect to only happen if the player is standing on top of the stool, rather than touching the side of it.

How can I modify this code to get the effect I want?

If it helps, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode employing arcade physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy/fast solution would be just to check, if the player is higher, than the stool, obviously taking the height and origin of both objects *(player and stool)* into consideration.

Since I don't know how your code looks like I can't add a demo to showcase this

**But it could have to look something like this:**
*(if the origin of both objects would be top left)*

```
if(this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.stool) &&
    (this.p1.y + this.p1.height) <= this.stool.y &&
     Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.keyW)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hey there. Checking if the player was higher than the stool appears to have worked, though I change (this.p1.y + this.p1.height) to just this.p1.y, as it wasn't working when I tried it. Granted, I haven't actually been setting the origin of any of the sprites in this project, so that may be why it didn't work. Should I still give you the check?

Comment: @EmptyStone Thank you for your feedback. Checkmarks and Votes are usually a very subjective. I personally give the checkmark if the answer solved or helped solve my problem **significantly**. As you explained your situation, I would give the checkmark, but is ofcourse up to you. btw.: If I can't give the checkmark to any answer, and find a soultion with the help of others answers, I might upvote the relevant answer(s), and write my own answer, since the checkmark signals to other users, that the question is solved, and which is a working solution.